# Simple command line calculator

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, calculator

Had one years ago (on Win 3.1 or '95, I'm not sure). Anyways, it was a really simple program. Stood somewhere in PATH and enabled you to do something of a kind

```
calc 5 + 28.3*sqrt(12)
```

and it spit out the result.

Anyone know of any such these days? Doesn't need to do anything fancy ... maybe it would just be nice if it had support for exponentials, but that's it.

Anyone?

*p.s. Not interested in full blown solutions like Python or MATLAB.*

Comment: Which OS are you using?  Many Operating Systems come with Perl pre-installed (if you're using Windows, you can use [Strawberry Perl](http://www.strawberryperl.com/) which is a very light-weight Perl distribution) and then create a shell script or a batch file called "calc" that is explained on this web page (this solution will handle complex math calculations for you too):  http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4400/a-command-line-calculator-in-perl

Comment: @RandolfRichardson - Sorry about that, always miss that part. Yeah, that's nice, but I'd rather see some up to two Mb solution, if such still exists. Portable Perl is nice, but 40Mb is hardly lightweight for a calc.

Comment: 40 MBs now?  Wow!  That is rather heavy just for a calculator.  =O

Comment: if i could remember how to code... this might be a simple afternoon's project in the computing language of my choice ;p

Comment: There is dc.exe in the gnuwin32 package, a port of the reverse polish notation command line calc for unix

Comment: Any update on the issue? Please mark an answer as correct if you feel it answers the question, or provide more information on why you don't feel they do.

Comment: @DanielAndersson - No, not much has changed. I haven't been able to get surfasb's answer to work. As to the rest, I'm not interested in installing either python or matlab for such a purpose, and as the last two go, I won't even think about converting such simple operations to awk.

Answer (score 1):

A google search pops up a few command line calculators.

This one is written in C#

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/command_line_calculator.aspx

This one does graphs also.
http://www.kotiposti.net/jjhalme/clcmain.htm

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [some flavour of awk](http://lifehacker.com/5396183/create-an-awesome-command-line-calculator) to do it - the link suggests creating a function like `calc(){ awk "BEGIN{ print $* }" ;}' and then using the new function with`calc "equation here"`- you can get a copy of awk from [unxutils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) or use [busybox](https://github.com/pclouds/busybox-w32).Either of them should be quite easily under 1 mb

For basic addition/subtraction/mulitiplication and division... try the `set /a` command - [more details here](http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/05/set-dos-command-line-calculator.html) and using the help option

Answer (score 0):

Google itself will perform such calculations in the search box or [here](http://www.google.ca/intl/en/help/features.html#calculator). Not sure what limitations it has though. Depends what you want to use this for.

Answer (score 0):

This started as a comment, but it became too long, so I post it as an answer.

You say you don't want Python, but Python *would* be quick and complete, and to compare Python and MATLAB in "full-blown"-ity is quite harsh. I believe it would also fare well speed wise compared the the C# and Perl suggestions among the comments and answers.

I use the one-liner:

```
python -ic "from __future__ import division; from math import *;"
```

which I've bound to a keyboard shortcut which opens a terminal with this command, which gives me a lightning-fast competent calculator with `exp()`, `sqrt()`, `sin()`, `log()`, `pi`, `e`, etc.

If you just want a "`calc 5+7`" variant, the *nix variete would be:

```
python -c "from __future__ import division; from math import *; print $*"
```

and on Windows you probably just need to replace `$*` with `%*`.

`from __future__ import division` makes division use floating point instead of integer division as default, which is expected of a calculator. This is not needed if one uses Python 3 (which is what the `__future__` part means).

`from math import *` imports all math functions into the main namespace, so you can do `sin(2*pi)` instead of `math.sin(2*pi)`.

---

As an encore: to have a script that can be started in either interactive or direct mode:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ ${#} = 0 ]; then
    python -ic "from __future__ import division; from math import *;"
else
    python -c "from __future__ import division; from math import *; print ${*};"
fi
```

(most probably trivially converted to Windows).